# What's this movie from the 80s-90s about the protagonist turning into a monster to fight the antagonist

Tags: story-identification, movie

I thought it might've been Watchers (1988) as it similarly had a scene involving a barn, but it's not it.

The only other scene I recall from the movie, besides having a scene in a barn, is that there's a scene somewhere--at a police station maybe?--in which the protagonist--some kid--transforms into some kind of creature to fight the antagonist.

Pretty vague, I know.

Comment: You might want to read [this post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/70236), which lists some details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: Who's trying to re-open this and why? Tells us why you think it should be re-opened as I see no extra details added since it was rightly closed for being 'too-broad'.

Answer (score 2):

Man, I'm throwing a guess out at the *Toxic Avenger* (1984). I also remember a barn.

> I don't know what came over me..

[Toxic Avenger Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27E4Qfj7iEY)

[image]

Comment: Is there anything else that matches the description in the questions?

Comment: Could have sworn after he first becomes the Toxic Avenger he runs super far away, through constructions sites and the city, then he stops and sleeps at a barn? Also, he was a very scrawny young 'nerd', and when he came across the toxic chemicals it turned him into a fierce nasty looking monster, but he was a GOOD guy. Your description made me think of the Toxic Avenger first thing.

Comment: Toxie only changes once towards the beginning, as I recall. The question makes it sound like he changes later in the film, and possibly multiple times.

Comment: @phantom42 See I could not remember that, I thought I had remembered him smashing some bad guys in, running through the city, then waking up in a barn (as the kid again), clothes tattered and torn. But it's been years, you are probably correct that he only changes once. EDIT: Looks like he changed back to his normal form in Toxic Avenger III for a little while at least.

Comment: I didn't expect so many replies so soon!  To answer your question, it's not The Toxic Avenger.  I don't even believe it was an R-rated movie that I saw.  I saw it on TV over a decade ago, and all I remember was the protagonist mutating into some kind of creature in order to fight the antagonist, who also mutated.  The protagonist was a kid while the antagonist was a middle-aged man.  The transformation could be turned on or off, it wasn't permanent.  It had to have been PG or PG-13 if that narrows it down a bit.  Definitely an 80s-90s movie, at the very least.

Comment: They mutated into some kind of animal humanoids if that helps.